# Optimize subqueries with LEFT JOINS MYSQL

Tags: mysql, left-join

I hope you can help me! I currently have this query:

```
SELECT servicio.*,
c.num_cliente,c.nombre,c.operador,
mdl.modelo_marca,mdl.modelo_telcel,
col.colores,
prob.problema,
diag.notas,diag.solucion,diag.tipo_servicios AS tipo_servicios_diagnostico,diag.nuevo_imei AS nuevo_imei_diagnostico,
diag.nivel_repar,diag.notasqc AS diagnos_notasqc,diag.fecha AS diagnos_fecha,diag.notas AS diagnos_notas,
user_name.nombre AS name_user,user_name.apellido,
(SELECT revision.status2_ser FROM revision WHERE revision.status2_ser IN('ENTREGADO') AND servicio.id = revision.id_servicio  ORDER BY revision.id DESC LIMIT 1) AS status2_ser,
(SELECT revision.fecha_status FROM revision WHERE revision.status2_ser IN('ENTREGADO') AND servicio.id = revision.id_servicio  ORDER BY revision.id DESC LIMIT 1) AS fecha_status_revision,
(SELECT revision.status2_ser FROM revision WHERE revision.status2_ser IN('REPARADO') AND servicio.id = revision.id_servicio  ORDER BY revision.id DESC LIMIT 1) AS status2_ser_repadado,
(SELECT revision.fecha_status FROM revision WHERE revision.status2_ser IN('REPARADO') AND servicio.id = revision.id_servicio  ORDER BY revision.id DESC LIMIT 1) AS revi2_fecha_status_revision,
(SELECT env.guia_entrega FROM envios AS env WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(env.envio_grupal, JSON_ARRAY(CAST(servicio.id AS CHAR))) OR env.id_servicio = servicio.id ORDER BY env.id DESC LIMIT 1) as guia_entrega_envio,
(SELECT env2.fecha_envio FROM envios AS env2 WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(env2.envio_grupal, JSON_ARRAY(CAST(servicio.id AS CHAR))) OR env2.id_servicio = servicio.id ORDER BY env2.id DESC LIMIT 1) as guia_entrega_envio_fecha
FROM servicio
LEFT JOIN usuarios AS user_name ON servicio.id_user = user_name.id
LEFT JOIN clientes AS c ON servicio.id_cac = c.id
LEFT JOIN modelos AS mdl ON servicio.id_modelo = mdl.id
LEFT JOIN colores AS col ON servicio.id_color = col.id
LEFT JOIN problemas_genericos AS prob ON CAST(servicio.problema_generico AS UNSIGNED) = prob.id
LEFT JOIN diagnostico AS diag ON diag.id = (SELECT id FROM diagnostico AS diag WHERE diag.id_servicio = servicio.id AND diag.tipo_servicios <> '' ORDER BY diag.id DESC LIMIT 1)
WHERE
servicio.fecha_ingreso >= '2022-03-07 00:00:00' AND servicio.fecha_ingreso <= '2022-03-16 23:59:59' AND servicio.status_ser IN('ENTREGADO') AND servicio.id_marca = 1
ORDER BY servicio.id DESC
```

the query works, but the performance is not as expected, it sometimes takes up to 10 seconds to retrieve more than 1000 records, the main table where I consult this data has approximately 210,000 records, could someone help me to make it more optimal please?

This is my explain:

[EXPLAIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfKKy.png)

Update my query but not there changes in the performance:

```
SELECT servicio.*,
c.num_cliente,c.nombre,c.operador,
mdl.modelo_marca,mdl.modelo_telcel,
col.colores,
prob.problema,
diag.notas,diag.solucion,diag.tipo_servicios AS tipo_servicios_diagnostico,diag.nuevo_imei AS nuevo_imei_diagnostico,
diag.nivel_repar,diag.notasqc AS diagnos_notasqc,diag.fecha AS diagnos_fecha,diag.notas AS diagnos_notas,
user_name.nombre AS name_user,user_name.apellido,
(SELECT env.guia_entrega FROM envios AS env WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(env.envio_grupal, JSON_ARRAY(CAST(servicio.id AS CHAR))) OR env.id_servicio = servicio.id ORDER BY env.id DESC LIMIT 1) as guia_entrega_envio,
(SELECT env2.fecha_envio FROM envios AS env2 WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(env2.envio_grupal, JSON_ARRAY(CAST(servicio.id AS CHAR))) OR env2.id_servicio = servicio.id ORDER BY env2.id DESC LIMIT 1) as guia_entrega_envio_fecha,
(CASE WHEN x.sta = 'ENTREGADO' THEN x.sta END) AS status2_ser,
(CASE WHEN x.sta = 'ENTREGADO' THEN x.g_fecha_status END) AS fecha_status_revision,
(CASE WHEN w.sta = 'REPARADO' THEN w.sta END) AS revi2_fecha_status_revision,
(CASE WHEN w.sta = 'REPARADO' THEN w.g_fecha_status END) AS revi2_fecha_status_revision
FROM servicio
LEFT JOIN usuarios AS user_name ON servicio.id_user = user_name.id
LEFT JOIN clientes AS c ON servicio.id_cac = c.id
LEFT JOIN modelos AS mdl ON servicio.id_modelo = mdl.id
LEFT JOIN colores AS col ON servicio.id_color = col.id
LEFT JOIN problemas_genericos AS prob ON CAST(servicio.problema_generico AS UNSIGNED) = prob.id
LEFT JOIN diagnostico AS diag ON diag.id = (SELECT id FROM diagnostico AS diag WHERE diag.id_servicio = servicio.id AND diag.tipo_servicios <> '' ORDER BY diag.id DESC LIMIT 1)

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT revision.status2_ser AS sta, revision.id_servicio,max(revision.fecha_status) AS g_fecha_status
    FROM revision
    WHERE revision.status2_ser IN("ENTREGADO")
    GROUP BY revision.id_servicio) x ON servicio.id = x.id_servicio
    
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT revision.status2_ser AS sta, revision.id_servicio,max(revision.fecha_status) AS g_fecha_status
    FROM revision
    WHERE revision.status2_ser IN("REPARADO")
    GROUP BY revision.id_servicio) w ON servicio.id = w.id_servicio

WHERE
servicio.fecha_ingreso >= '2022-03-07 00:00:00' AND servicio.fecha_ingreso <= '2022-03-16 23:59:59' AND servicio.status_ser IN('ENTREGADO') AND servicio.id_marca = 1
ORDER BY servicio.id DESC
```

Comment: I think you should create `view` for this result or cache it

Comment: @Joseph Thanks for answering friend, adding it to cache is good when it is a query for a report?

Comment: yes add all the reports in a `cache` or `view`

Comment: @Joseph, FYI, MySQL views do not store any data results. They execute the defined query every time you query the view. So views would not help to improve performance.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for mention that so in this case cache would be fine i think

Comment: @Joseph would the cache not affect if any of the data changes?

Comment: @BillKarwin would cache help?

Comment: if this data is frequently updated so cache won't help in this case

Comment: @Joseph unfortunately if it is consulted frequently :(

Comment: Often you won't need all the results, only a tiny selection. Can't you use this to minimize the number of subqueries you need to perform? And certainly translate columns with JSON in them to normal columns.

Comment: Caching the result of a query does not help a query perform better. But if the data doesn't change, you can read from the cache many times for each time you need to run the query to generate the result to store in the cache. One can assume that reading from the cache is much quicker than running the query.

Comment: FWIW, I skip questions asking for query-optimization help unless they provide the table definitions and the current result of `EXPLAIN` for their query. It's best if you create a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.co.uk) demo, so folks can reproduce the query and test potential optimizations. Please avoid the temptation to post screenshots of your tables or the EXPLAIN.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware in this case if all the records are required, because previously try to section the results

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html

Comment: Can you include the tables `envios` and `revision` in the join and avoid running 6 sub-queries per line? I'm not surprised that it is slow.

Comment: @Kendle in fact it is what I am trying to do, I want to summarize that part to avoid doing several sub queries

Comment: Put everything needed to as your question in your post as [text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). [ask] [Help] [mre] Research is expected, there are many SO Q&A & other resources re basics of query optimization & asking about query optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- These indexes may help:

  ```
  servicio:  INDEX(id_marca, fecha_ingreso, status_ser)
  servicio:  INDEX(id_marca, status_ser, fecha_ingreso)
  revision:  INDEX(status2_ser, id_servicio, id,  fecha_status)
  envios:  INDEX(envio_grupal, id_servicio, id,  guia_entrega)
  envios:  INDEX(envio_grupal, id_servicio, id,  fecha_envio)
  diag:  INDEX(id_servicio, tipo_servicios, id)
  ```

When adding a composite index, DROP index(es) with the same leading columns.
That is, when you have both INDEX(a) and INDEX(a,b), toss the former.

- I see some cases of the same subquery being performed twice because you needed two columns.  Recommend you use a `LEFT JOIN` to get both columns at the same time.
- If you regularly need to test things inside a JSON column, especially if the types are need CASTing, consider adding an extra column to the table to make it easily testable without all the Json overhead.
- (This *may* eliminate a sort without changing the effect.)  Replace `ORDER BY  servicio.id DESC` with `ORDER BY  fecha_ingreso DESC, servicio.id DESC`
- `ON CAST(servicio.problema_generico AS UNSIGNED) = prob.id` probably prevents use of an index.  See if you can fix the datatypes to avoid the need for `CAST`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rick James, now works better!